# Summing over the values of a dict

Tags: python, beginner

I'm coming from the Java world and making my first steps on Python and see how good it is to express more with less code. I'd like to know if, via Python, the size of the following code could be reduced:

```
column_entropy = 0
for k in frequencies.keys():
    p = frequencies[k] / 10
    column_entropy += p * log(p, 2) if p > 0 else 0
column_entropy = -column_entropy
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `frequencies` is a `dict`, then the code could be reduced and optimized a little bit by iterating over the items in it instead of the keys and then doing a lookup,
like this:

```
column_entropy = 0
for k, v in frequencies.items():
    p = v / 10
    column_entropy += p * log(p, 2) if p > 0 else 0
column_entropy = -column_entropy
```

And, if you change `+=` to `-=` then you can drop the final negation of `column_entropy`.

---

Actually, it would be nice to give a name to the calculation inside the loop:

```
def calculate(k, v):
    p = v / 10
    return p * log(p, 2) if p > 0 else 0
```

With the help of this function, the complete calculation becomes:

```
column_entropy = -sum([calculate(k, v) for k, v in frequencies.items()])
```

This is just an example, you should give better names to all of these,
according to what they represent:

- `calculate`
- `k`
- `v`

Note that in Python you can define functions inside functions.
This is perfectly legal (and I'd go as far as to say recommended):

```
def calculate_column_entropy(frequencies):
    def calculate(k, v):
        p = v / 10
        return p * log(p, 2) if p > 0 else 0

    return -sum([calculate(k, v) for k, v in frequencies.items()])
```

The good thing about inner functions is that they have a name:
instead of writing a comment to explain what the body of a `for` loop does,
you can express the same information by giving it a name.
And you never know,
you might want to reuse that function multiple times, later in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The [formula for calculating entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) is:

$$ \sum_i p_i \log\frac{1}{p_i} $$

or \$-\sum p_i \log p_i\$. It would be nice if the code could express that.

```
probabilities = [f / 10 for f in frequencies.values() if f > 0]
column_entropy = -sum(p * log(p, 2) for p in probabilities)
```

The second line is the goal — it's a direct translation of the formula.  The first line is the setup that makes it possible to write the second line nicely.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one line if you need (untested). But I suggest you stick in to @jonas's method for now.

```
-sum([ (x/10) * log(x/10, 2) for x in frequencies.values() if x/10 > 0 ])
```